# Can repeated calls to the same function provide better performance?

Tags: c

I have code that looks like this:

```
void foo(unsigned long k)
{
    if (k & 1)
    {
        bar(k/2 + 1);
        bar(k/2);
        bar(k/2 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        bar(k/2);
        bar(k/2);
        bar(k/2);
    }
}

void bar(unsigned long k)
{
  switch(k)
  {
     case default: special_default(); break;
     case 1: specialbar1(); break;
     case 2: specialbar2(); break;
     <more cases>
     case 16: specialbar16(); break;
  }
}
```

The performance is much better when `foo` is called for an even value of `k`. Each of the `specialbar#()` methods uses several stack variables, the number of such variables increases sharply as `k` increases. To be clear `specialbar#()` makes use of about `3 * k` local variables all of which are `unsigned long long` variables.

For example `foo(32)` executes about 15% faster than `foo(31)`. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the performance analysis assures me that two calls to `specialbar16` and one call to `specialbar15` takes considerably more work than three consecutive calls to `specialbar16`.

Is it possible that the compiler takes advantage of the three consecutive calls when `k` is even? That is, can it realize that the stack is essentially the same over the three consecutive calls for even `k` yet the same optimization is not possible for odd `k`?

Comment: You aren't really measuring the same thing because you are calling different `specialbar_k()` functions in each case, and they presumably do different things.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that the compiler takes advantage of the three consecutive calls when k is even? That is can it realize that the stack is essentially the same over the three consecutive calls for even k yet the same optimization is not possible for odd k?

This hardly seems worthy of an answer but, yes, that's entirely possible. The compiler may recognize that the same stack layout is required for each call due it it being the same method each time, and thus avoid the whole stack setup/teardown for each method call. It is in this case probably also inlining the method call - the code is generated in place in the caller.

Most likely similar optimization could be performed for the other case as well, though optimization is tricky and there are sometimes subtle reasons why a compiler won't be able to perform it.

Comment: Perhaps then it would be best to replace the specialbar#() methods with equivalent methods that each deal with an even k value together with the corresponding k - 1 value. However I thought this less readable and a bit pedantic. Would one go to such lengths when one notices that it would be best to have consecutive calls to the same method?

Comment: I'd personally advise that trying to outsmart the optimising compiler is a bad move. Is performance really so important that you need to consider doing this? You may end up slowing down both cases.

Comment: @davmac, "outsmarting" the compiler it's ok for optimizing purposes IFF it is the last thing you do AND you require that last speed boost. However, from a portability perspective, you're right, it is a bad move.

Comment: @Adrian, of course it's ok if you really need the speed, it's just that (a) you may not be successful and (b) you usually don't really need the speed.

Answer (score 1):

You're foo function performs extra logic when k is odd (k/2 + 1) the + 1.

To answer your specific question, can repeated calls improve performance. Yes it can when the parameters are the same the tranches within the function are the same and this allows for "branch prediction" to work optimally.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link to further information on branch prediction, any direction would be most helpful.

Comment: @Peter - Search for branch prediction, http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/ There's also cache residency, because the function is already in your processor cache the subsequent calls to it will be faster because there won't be any loading or cache misses to get the op codes.